# Dimensional modeling for sales fact with product and inventory dimension

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I am building a dimensional model for sales analysis that has a fact called Sales and is linked with a Product dimension.

Point is that for each day the Product inventory will change, and this information is important for them to analyse why a specific product wasn't sold (for example, on day XX/XX the product 123456 wasn't sold because there where no products in the inventory).

I'd like to know the best option to modeling this situation and if possible a short explanation about how it'd work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad discussion question, so here' some discussion.

**Dimension tables**

```
--  Products  -----
ProductId
Name
 (etc.)
```

Contains one row per product being tracked
ProductId should be a surrogate key

```
--  Time  --------
TimeId
ReportingPeriod (Q1, week 17, whatever as desired)
 (etc.)
```

Contains one row for every day being tracked.
Once the results of a day’s activities are known, it can be added to the warehouse

Note that TimeId does not have to be a surrogate key

**Fact tables**

```
--  Inventory  -------------------------
ProductId
TimeId
```

Once the results of a day’s activities are known, they can be added to the warehouse
One row (per day) for each product, listing the inventory available as of the end of that day

But then it gets complex: just what data is needed, and what data is availabe? Assuming the data is for one day, possible facts to track and record include:

```
StartingInventory  -- What you had at the start of the day
UnitsReceived  --  Units received for storage today
UnitsSold  --  Units sold (that cannot be sold again) but not yet shipped
UnitsShipped  --  Units shipped (sold or otherwise)
EndingInventory  --  Units in stock at end of day
```

It gets complex fast. Again, much depends on what information you have available and what questions will be asked of your warehouse.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!! In our case, our fact table would be Sales (total of product sold, total amount of sales - per product, customer, store, etc). Based on my understanding, they want to track an issue like "Ok, this product was in around 40 sales per day last week and this week its sales decreased 70%. Was it because there is no more of it in the inventory?". Maybe the solution to track this information is through a historic table, but I am not sure how it would work.

Comment: Another thing is that there will be other metrics within the fact table, like Medium Ticket, Average Number of Sold Products, Max Price Paid, Min Price Paid... In this case, how would be the best thing to to as some metrics wouldn't make sense in the fact (e.g. Medium Ticket per Product: if the fact is detailed by product, this information will be the same as "number of products sold", right?)

Comment: Not quite sure what "Medium Ticket" means. If it is a fact to which individual product does not apply, make a separate fact table (perhaps table DaySummary, columsn TimeId, TotalSales, MediumTicket, etc. ?)

Comment: Medium Ticket is the average amount of money earned over the total number of sales (one sale of $3 and one of $7, MT = $5). My Sales fact will have some visions: by time, store, product, region, category (of a product), brand, etc). The types of analysis we'll be extracting are like "what product was more sold in a given period of time?", or "today, what were the 10 most sold products by hour?". I am not sure how I should structure my Fact table.

Comment: Sounds like a grain question. If you record each individual sale in your warehouse, you can calculate just about anything; if you store aggregates (total sales for day), you can lose precision (such as sold per hour). Kind of outside the scope of this question, really.